# How do I partition efficiently in SQL Server based on foreign keys?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, partitioning

I am working on SQL Server and want to create a partition on a table. I want to base it off of a foreign key which is in another table.

```
table1 (
   fk uniqueidentifier,
   data
)
```

fk points to table2

```
table 2 (
    partition element here
)
```

I want to partition table1 base on table2's data, ie if table2 contains categories

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The foreign key relationship doesn't really matter, horizontal partitioning is based on the values in the table itself.  The foreign key just makes sure they already exist in another table.

Links:

- [SQL SERVER – 2005 – Database Table Partitioning Tutorial – How to Horizontal Partition Database Table](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/01/25/sql-server-2005-database-table-partitioning-tutorial-how-to-horizontal-partition-database-table/)
- [Partitioning a SQL Server Database Table](http://databases.about.com/od/sqlserver/a/partitioning.htm)
- [Steps for Creating Partitioned Tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345146%28SQL.90%29.aspx#sql2k5parti_topic12)

Comment: wasnt too clear, I want to partition base on another table which is linked by da foreign key